# python search string for numbers, put brackets around them

Tags: python, regex, insert, numbers

I'm trying to search a string for numbers, and when finding them, wrap some chars around them, e.g.

```
a = "hello, i am 8 years old and have 12 toys"
a = method(a)
print a
"hello, i am \ref{8} years old and have \ref{12} toys"
```

I've looked at the re (regular expression) library, but cannot seem to find anything helpful... any cool ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty basic usage of the `.sub` method:

```
numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

a = numbers.sub(r'\ref{\1}', a)
```

The parethesis around the `\d+` number pattern create a group, and the `\1` reference is replaced with the contents of the group.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "hello, i am 8 years old and have 12 toys"
>>> numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
>>> a = numbers.sub(r'\\ref{\1}', a)
>>> print a
hello, i am \ref{8} years old and have \ref{12} toys
```

Comment: it puts the \ref{} at the correct position, but removes the number... What could be wrong?

Comment: The first backslash needs to be escaped in sub: `r'\\ref{\1}'`. (Try `print a`)

Comment: i tried a = numbers.sub(r'\ref{\0}', a), which didn't work, now when i try a = numbers.sub(r'\ref{\1}', a) it gives: sre_constants.error: invalid group reference

Comment: Make sure you are using a raw string or are escaping backslashes.

Comment: @Eldamir: Check your pattern; it should have a group (`r'(\d+)'`).

Comment: I was mission the parenthesis around the regex to create the group... thanks buddy

Comment: @DSM Using the raw string keeps the backslash intact when Python parses the source, but the regex engine still treats it as an escape char. I repeat: try `print a` after Martijn's example.

Comment: @JanneKarila: The `\r` escape is meaningless to the `.sub()` method, and it is ignored. The `\r` escapes only have meaning to Python, and the OP example output included these as literals. It may well be that he *meant* to have a literal backslash in his output instead of the `\r` escape code, of course.

Comment: @JanneKarila: ah, I take your point!  [Hey, it's 6:40 AM in my timezone.]

Comment: @MartijnPieters The OP uses `print a` for example output so I presume literal backlash is wanted. (Though the quotes should also disappear in `print`)

Comment: @JanneKarila: Fair enough; not sure why I thought it was being echoed, not printed, must have looked at my own answer instead. :-P Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use re.sub function along these lines :

`re.sub("(\d+)",my_sub_func,text)` # catch the numbers here (altho this only catches non real numbers)
where my_sub_func is defined like this :

`def my_sub_func(match_obj):`

```
    text = match_obj.group(0) # get the digit text here
    new_text = "\\ref{"+text+"}" # change the pattern here
    return new_text`
```

Comment: `.sub()` supports substitution patterns, a function is overkill here.